# What is the correct equation for this Exponential Growth problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

This is a exponential growth problem. The problem is "*A population of mosquito fish in a pond currently numbers 600. If the relative growth rate is 23% per week, write a function for the population t weeks from now. Also, how long will it take for the population to reach 10,000?*"

The equation I am using since its a exponential growth problem is y = a(1 + r)^t.

For the function for the population in t weeks I got y = (1 + 0.23)^t.
For how long it will take to reach 10,000, I got y = 600(1.23)^7.

The reason I did to the power of 7 for time is because there is 7 days in a week. However, I am not sure if I am correct or not.

It would take 2555 weeks for the population to reach 10,000.

Comment: Just find the value of $t$ such that $10000 = 600(1.23)^t$. This will give you the time in weeks; there is no reason to think about days or how many days there are in a week.

Comment: Great! I didn't know you could do it like that. Thank you.